# Jquery - fadeIn - jerky fadein

Tags: jquery, queue, fadein

I've made a simple image switcher that fades different logos in and out. Example and full source code at http://bit.ly/ewrSgp . I fadeout the image, then queue a src attribute change, then fade back in. It seems to work smoothly for a while but after 20 seconds or so it starts to fade the image back in before changing the src, which then changes instantly and  looks ugly. Am I doing this right?

The code that runs the change is:

```
// fadeout old image, change to new and fadeback in.
// Call function changeimage again.
$(imToChange).fadeOut(600).queue(function (n) {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', newimageSrc);
    n();
}).fadeIn(1000, function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        //recall image change function
        changeImage(indexToChange);
    }, o.delay);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw some flickers, but not many. I noticed that it happened on a particular logo, I think the first time I saw it, but not the next time, which makes me think that once it's loaded, it's fine. Some thoughts:

- Does this happen if the images are all local (and hence load very quickly)?
- Have you tried [preloading the images](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript)?
- If preloading works, what do you think about putting them all in a sprite? Only one http request to make.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I did have a preload function but I was missing storing to the cache part from that tut, so I think it must have been overwriting before even loading, but this seems to have fixed it. Will look into the other options you suggested below too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wait for the image to finish loading. I'd try displaying the image outside the visible area or behind some other image until the onload event fires, then move it and fade it in at the proper location.

Something like this.

```
var img = $("<img href='newimage.png' />").load(function() { movit(); fadeit(); });
$("#ahiddenelement").append(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: instead of changing the source of the image, how about using jQuery's `.load()` or `.get()` to replace it? Then you could use a callback function, which only fires after the loading is done, to fade it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Specify width and height for *img* tag.